# register relationship

Tags: fflib

I am using the unit of work design pattern ([fflib](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_patterns_sl/apex_patterns_sl_apply_uow_principles)) to persist objects; however, it does not register relationships, code as follows:

```
fflib_SObjectUnitOfWork uow = new fflib_SObjectUnitOfWork(
        new List<SObjectType>{
                Opportunity.SObjectType, Account.SObjectType
        }
);

Account acc = new Account(Name = 'Test Account', Type = 'Customer', Phone = '000');
uow.registerNew(acc);

Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(Name = 'Test Opportunity 1', CloseDate = Date.today(), StageName = 'Open');
uow.registerRelationship(opp, Opportunity.AccountId, acc);
uow.registerNew(opp);

uow.commitWork();
```

It persists the opportunity without the account id:

> (Opportunity:{Id=0068E00000Orwd8QAB, Name=Test Opportunity 1, AccountId = null})

All triggers, workflows, etc are disabled.

Can you please help?

Comment: Might need to see some debug logs. It looks like it should work from what I can see, at least.

Answer (score 3):

Objects passed to the constructor of `fflib_SObjectUnitOfWork` **must be** in dependency order for the `commitWork()` method to insert them in the correct order. In your case `Account.SObjectType` must be placed before `Opportunity.SObjectType`:

```java
fflib_SObjectUnitOfWork uow = new fflib_SObjectUnitOfWork(
        new List<SObjectType>{
                Account.SObjectType,
                Opportunity.SObjectType
        }
);
```

We added first the `Account` as it is needed to be inserted first in order to populate the lookup ID’s on the `Opportunity`.

Result:

```
{
  "attributes" : {
    "type" : "Opportunity",
    "url" : "/services/data/v51.0/sobjects/Opportunity/0061j00000Ekf40AAB"
  },
  "Name" : "Test Opportunity 1",
  "AccountId" : "0011j000012wrv9AAA",
  "Id" : "0061j00000Ekf40AAB"
}
```